# Am i handling sessions right?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I need some help with sessions on PHP, I'm making a user account system I was told that they're made using PHP sessions, I searched for some tips and made some tests, I ended up with this code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myuser";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = 'mydb';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST["submitbutton"])){

$user = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user = '".$user."' AND password = '".$password."'"));

if(!empty($usuario["user"]) || !empty($usuario["password"])){

    $cookie_name = "cookie";
    setcookie($cookie_name, " ", time() - (86400 * 30), "/");

    $id = session_create_id();
    $cookie_value = $id;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

    session_id($id);
    session_start();

    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    header("Location:home.php");

} else{
    echo "Error, password incorrect";
}

}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HOME</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>LOGIN</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>Usuário:</p>
        <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
        <p>Senha:</p>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <p><input type="submit" value="Enter" name="submitbutton"><br></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

So basically it is a form that checks if it was filled and proceeds to verify if the user params (user and password) match one in a database, if the data matches, it erases the site's cookie, creates a session id, creates a cookie and stores the session id on it, stores the session id, stores user data in the session, starts the session and redirects to the home page.

them in the home.php page I have a code to check if the user is logged, it does by checking if the cookie stored id matches the session id:

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE["cookie"])) {

$session = $_COOKIE["cookie"];
session_start();
if (session_id() === $session){
//does nothing
} else {
    $cookie_name = "cookie";
    $cookie_value = session_id();
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() - (86400 * 30), "/");
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");    
}

} else{
header("Location:index.php");   
}
?>
```

This code is supposed to run on every page of the system, if the ids do not match, it finishes the session, erases the cookie and redirects to the login page, if it does not have a site cookie, it redirects to the login page.

Is this the way to do it? Is this code alright?

Comment: Does this work ?  This site is to find out what is wrong with your code.  So, you need to tell us where it goes wrong.

Comment: Definitely not. You made it unnecessarily complicated and messy. Simply start a session, write the user info into $_SESSION["user"] and call it a day. What is much more important, all this code is just useless, because anyone will just login without a password through SQL injection.

Comment: I made a SQL database to list the users credentials on the system, so when the user fills the form it verifies if the credentials match an user from the list, how can i make it verify users from the database without being easy to invade?